# Firebase using React JS: Can't add Docs on without a setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and firestore. I can query easily. But when it comes to setting new data my promise isn't resolving. It's a quite strange error. Any help is appreciated.

```js
firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const myFirebase = firebase
export const myFirestore = firebase.firestore()
export const myStorage = firebase.storage()

setTimeout(() => {
  const messages = myFirestore.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Anglssssss",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });  
}, 1000);
```

The above prints 'Document successfully written'

But the following doesn't print anything. not even from the catch block.

```js
firebase.initializeApp(config)
// firebase.firestore().settings({
//     timestampsInSnapshots: true

export const myFirebase = firebase
export const myFirestore = firebase.firestore()
export const myStorage = firebase.storage()

const messages = myFirestore.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
  name: "Los Anglssssss",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
})
.then(function () {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: The main difference that I see in the code blocks is that in the one above, your `set` operation will be delayed 1 sec, whereas the one below, your `set` operation won't experience any delay. If you executed these code snippets in a sequence, it's likely that you already have this data in your database, and you may be just replacing/overwriting it over and over again. Have you tried the second block to adding new data? What does your database structure look like? Please show the error that you are receiving.

Comment: yes, that's the only difference. If there is no delay set doesn't work. I executed them separately to compare the results. I also made sure the data is different. I don't get any error. It just fails silently.